# 3D зеркальное отображение карт

Tags: css, html5, css3, анимация, css-animation

Я пытаюсь сделать  эффект зеркального отображения  3D-карты с помощью CSS, как на примере ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разница заключается в том, что я хочу использовать чистый CSS для  реализации эффекта.

Ниже мой код:

```css
/*** LESS: ***/

    .card-container {
        position: relative;
        height: 12rem;
        width: 9rem;
        perspective: 30rem;
        .card {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;            
            div {
                position: absolute;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }
            .front {
                background-color: #66ccff;
            }
            .back {
                background-color: #dd8800;
                backface-visibility: hidden;
                transition: transform 1s;
                &:hover {
                    transform: rotateY(180deg);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front"><span>Front</span></div>
    <div class="back"><span>Back</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

После попыток, в течение нескольких часов, я смог  получить только следующий эффект:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли реализовать этот эффект `card flip`, используя только CSS?

**комментарии:**

"front" не получает анимации. Установите его вращение на `180, 360` при наведении на него. Положение `360` градусов должно быть похоже на `0`, но при этом должно поддерживаться то же направление вращения. - @[Yemachu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7155825/yemachu)

источник: [3D flipping card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41461101/3d-flipping-card/41462226#41462226)

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41461101/3d-flipping-card/41462226#41462226

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Я упростил код, чтобы сделать его короче. Было несколько вопросов, и ниже, на рисунке, как  они выглядят:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- передняя поверхность не поворачивается при наведении курсора мыши
- `hover` эффект   запуcкается, при наведение курсора на `.back div` .
  Это может создать мерцание, а затем `div` вращается. Это лучше, чтобы
  запустить анимацию, иначе родитель зависнет.
- первый родитель не очень полезен, так что я убрал его.

  Ниже приведен пример простого эффекта CSS, только `flipping card` флип анимация запускается при наведении курсора мыши:

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 9rem; height: 12rem;
  perspective: 30rem;
}
.front, .back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  transition: transform 1s;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}
.front { 
  background-color: #66ccff; 
}
.back { 
  background-color: #dd8800; 
  transform: rotateY(180deg); 
}
.card:hover .front{ transform: rotateY(180deg); }
.card:hover .back { transform: rotateY(360deg); }
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="front"><span>Front</span></div>
  <div class="back"><span>Back</span></div>
</div>
```

Ответил: [web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki)